# How do I mount my local directory in docker-compose so that my Dockerfile can copy files from it?

Tags: docker-compose, copy, dockerfile, volume

I'm using Docker 19.  I have this in my docker-compose.yml file ...

```
  python:
    restart: always
    build: ./python
    #ports:           # to access the container from outside
    #  - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    #command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn directory.wsgi:application --reload -w 2 -b :8000
    volumes:
    - /Users/davea/projects/my_python_project:/my-app
    depends_on:
      - sql-server-db
```

On my local file system, note that I have this file, in the mounted volume ...

```
$ ls /Users/davea/projects/my_python_project/requirements.txt 
/Users/davea/projects/my_python_project/requirements.txt
```

The Python Dockerfile begins like so

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get install -y g++

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /my-app/

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

However, when I run docker-compose up, it dies with this error

```
ERROR: Service 'python' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder959559160/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

I'm confused about how to name my volume so that Docker can access the proper file.

Answer (score 0):

In your the Dockerfile the command "COPY" tries to copy a file from "./python/requirements.txt" which doesn't exist in the current [docker build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Since you have the file you wish to copy in a docker volume, you could mount that volume to the docker containers desired location and remove the COPY command from your Dockerfile.
The other option is to place the "requirements.txt" to the "./python/" directory you're using in your docker-compose.